# Examples of the use for the factory design pattern in C#

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I understand the theory behind the factory design pattern now, but can't seem to find any realistic examples of it's use. Can someone be as kind enough as to provide one?

Comment: Bandwagon - the only reason this question is about to be closed. I'm all ears as to other reasons...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few variants of factory designs: abstract factory, factory method, etc... Since you're interested in a real-world example, I thought I'd share what I did.

As one example, I used a data access factory to return a concrete instance of a data access class. The logic class doesn't know or care which database is being used; it simply asks the factory for a data class, and then uses that data class.

This is the method within my DataAccessFactory class. It is responsible for determing which data class to use, and returning it to the caller:

```
public static T GetDataInterface<T>() where T : class
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    T theObject = (from t in assembly.GetTypes()
                   where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(T))
                     && t.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) != null
                     && t.Namespace == _namespace
                   select Activator.CreateInstance(t) as T).FirstOrDefault() as T;

    return theObject as T;
}
```

And this is how one of my business logic classes makes a DAL request:

```
return DataAccessFactory.GetDataInterface<IApplicationData>().GetAll();
```

The business logic is completely decoupled from the data access layer. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As your question is extremely general just some links on the subject with examples etc.:

- http://www.dotnetperls.com/factory
- [Factory Design Pattern (needing critique)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099969/factory-design-pattern-needing-critique)
- http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternAbstract.aspx#_self2
- http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57421/Design-Patterns-Part-2-The-Factory-Pattern

The pattern is used in the .NET framework - for example with [`WebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw00b1dc.aspx).

Comment: It's not *really* extremely general - I'm asking for a realistic example of where the factory design pattern can be used. How advanced or in what way the factory design pattern example is is at the discretion of whoever chooses to answer my question - it'd be good to see a range of examples. +1 anyway for your answer, thanks for the links, I'll read them now.

Comment: @SkonJeet you are welcome :-) added an example from the .NET framework...